# Calculating PRESS statistic using own data set produces error in R

Tags: r, package, dataset, data-science

I was attempting to calculate the PRESS statistic using the `PRESS()` function from the `qpcR` package. I first create the regression function from data I imported:

```
> job_proficiency_lm_first_order_formula_best = job_proficiency ~ T_1 + T_3 + T_4
> job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs = lm(data = Job_Proficiency, formula = job_proficiency_lm_first_order_formula_best)
> summary(job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs)

Call:
lm(formula = job_proficiency_lm_first_order_formula_best, data = Job_Proficiency)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.4579 -3.1563 -0.2057  1.8070  6.6083 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -124.20002    9.87406 -12.578 3.04e-11 ***
T_1            0.29633    0.04368   6.784 1.04e-06 ***
T_3            1.35697    0.15183   8.937 1.33e-08 ***
T_4            0.51742    0.13105   3.948 0.000735 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.072 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9615,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.956 
F-statistic:   175 on 3 and 21 DF,  p-value: 5.16e-15
```

As you can see the regression function is calculated with out a hitch.

But when I attempt to calculate the `PRESS` statistic I get the following:

```
> PRESS(object = job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs)
.
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'T_1' not found
```

To test that the `PRESS()` function itself was working I attempted to get the PRESS statistic with a built in data set from `R`, particularly the `swiss` data set:

```
> test = lm(data = swiss, formula = Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination)
> PRESS(test)
.........10.........20.........30.........40.......
$stat
[1] 4594.711

$residuals
 [1]   5.86874937  -0.11299684   8.99475044   9.63703923   6.86207418  -4.99681787  15.67581939  21.66065932   7.37038439  11.95400827  15.75323917   0.44045951  -4.80167644
[14]   2.81771330  -0.11677715   2.18088788   0.62738886  -6.43338393  -2.03263398   0.06287026   2.99119927  -7.88458225  -7.23342328  -8.51283184  -1.12064764   1.82564228
[27] -10.11322228  -9.54214928  -4.12165698  -6.78996076  -8.18443581  -9.65615193  -3.18410523  -2.56286583  -0.78611489 -12.32904436  10.00836421   6.33398831  11.08423270
[40]   7.20518930   6.42985483  15.41461736   4.64693055   4.94386095 -18.45443801 -27.04073067 -23.95733041

$P.square
[1] 0.3598858
```

As can be seen there was no issue. So it must be something occurring under the hood. So I'm here to inquire what could possibly be the issue I'm encountering?

For reference here is my imported data set it is not too large hopefully it doesn't violate any rules:

```
> dput(Job_Proficiency)
structure(list(job_proficiency = c(88, 80, 96, 76, 80, 73, 58, 
116, 104, 99, 64, 126, 94, 71, 111, 109, 100, 127, 99, 82, 67, 
109, 78, 115, 83), T_1 = c(86, 62, 110, 101, 100, 78, 120, 105, 
112, 120, 87, 133, 140, 84, 106, 109, 104, 150, 98, 120, 74, 
96, 104, 94, 91), T_2 = c(110, 97, 107, 117, 101, 85, 77, 122, 
119, 89, 81, 120, 121, 113, 102, 129, 83, 118, 125, 94, 121, 
114, 73, 121, 129), T_3 = c(100, 99, 103, 93, 95, 95, 80, 116, 
106, 105, 90, 113, 96, 98, 109, 102, 100, 107, 108, 95, 91, 114, 
93, 115, 97), T_4 = c(87, 100, 103, 95, 88, 84, 74, 102, 105, 
97, 88, 108, 89, 78, 109, 108, 102, 110, 95, 90, 85, 103, 80, 
104, 83)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -25L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    job_proficiency = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), T_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), T_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), T_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), T_4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 0), class = "col_spec"))
```

EDIT: So the first error was corrected thanks to @Otto, but now I'm getting a different error:

```
> job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs = lm(data = Job_Proficiency, formula = job_proficiency ~ T_1 + T_3 + T_4)
> PRESS(job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs)
.........10.........20.....
Error in PRESS.res^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

All I did was enter my formula into the regression model manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `PRESS()` seems to expect the formula to be given as string. This works:

```
library('qpcR')
job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs = lm(data = Job_Proficiency, formula = job_proficiency ~ T_1 + T_3 + T_4)
PRESS(job_proficiency_lm_first_order_best_subs)
.........10
$stat
[1] 56.11556

$residuals
 [1]  4.24693620 -0.02950692 -0.24941392 -1.68812204  0.37184702 -3.35442911
 [7]  1.86363303 -1.48719175  3.34459605 -2.62766088

$P.square
[1] 0.9785162
```

Regarding your second error "`Error in PRESS.res^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`", I suspect that it is due to the fact that your Job_Proficiency is a tibble, and not a data.frame. The two representations of data are almost the same, [except when they are not.](https://www.rstudio.com/blog/tibble-1-0-0/)

Maybe the easiest way to tackle the second error is to transform your input data into a data.frame from tibble by

```
Job_Proficiency <- as.data.frame(Job_Proficiency)
```

and then proceeding with your analysis.

As far as I am concerned, both of the issues we found (formula cannot be pre-assigned, and tibbles cause errors) are clear bugs that should be reported to the package developer.

Comment: hmmm interesting....so I have to explicitly state the formula within my regression model....EDIT: Now I'm getting a different error.....

Comment: The data you posted does not replicate the error. Could you post a sample data that produces the error?

Comment: I just added the whole data set to my question and I was able to produce the error again.

Comment: @dc3rd try as.data.frame(Job_Proficiency) -> Job_Proficiency

Comment: My data is already a data frame.

Comment: No it is not, at least according to your dput() output. class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"). You probably read in your data using readr() so you end up importing a tibble.

Comment: well I did use `read_table2()` from the `tidyverse` package and I know they tend to lean towards tibbles. But when I asked the program I used `is.data.frame()` and it responded as `TRUE`....

Comment: It worked using your suggestion......Thanks. I'm going to try and report them to the developers